# Laravel, redirect to specific login page if user is not authenticated

Tags: php, laravel

I tried all the possible solutions to redirect user if not authenticated to different login pages due to their middleware but every time it takes me to /register, I modified Authenticate.php in middleware folder, as well as the middleware it self but still taking me to /register.
I want to redirect user to a specific login page if he is not login
so I have editor middleware so I want to redirect if someone tried to open the link /editor/dashboard and he is not authenticated the redirect him to /editorlogin

editor middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
if(auth()->user() && (auth()->user()->role_id == 3)) {
  return $next($request);   
 } else {
   return redirect()->intended('editorlogin'); 
  }
```

Route:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:web','editor'],'prefix' => 'writer'], function () {

 Route::get('/dashboard', 'Writer\WriterController@index')->name('writer.dashboard');



Route::resource('/store', 'Writer\StoreController');
```

Comment: please remove `auth:web` to only `web`  and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `auth:web` from `auth`

`web` is different midlleware and `auth` is diffrent

`auth` has diffrent redirect url that's why you are getting `auth` redirect url not your custom one

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','editor'],'prefix' => 'writer'], function () {
```

Comment: the same still redirect me to /register

Comment: register is not default laravel redirect guest url please check may be you have put somewhere